# #1054- Unknown column 'lng' in 'field list' error while fetching

Tags: mysql, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to get the users within a certain radius using this query

```
SELECT *, (3959 * acos(cos(radians(10.916089)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos( radians(lng) - radians(57.598873)) + sin(radians(10.916089)) * 
sin(radians(lat)))) 
AS distance 
FROM project_details WHERE distance < 15 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 10
```

But I'm getting this error

> #1054- Unknown column 'lng' in 'field list' error while fetching

What am I doing wrong?

My DB dataType for lat and lng is decimal(10,8) and decimal(11,8) respectively.

```
    CREATE TABLE `project_details` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `startDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `endDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `zipcode` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `lat` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `lng` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `createdBy` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `createdBy` (`createdBy`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Share table definition. Are you sure you have column named lng and not  "lng "?

Comment: Clearly there's no column named `lng`.  You may think there is, but MySQL is usually right about these things.

Comment: see there is a lng column

Comment: Change `WHERE` to `HAVING`, since `distance` is not available at the time that `WHERE` is performed.

Answer (score 0):

I try to recreate you case and I don't get error with `lng` but with `WHERE condition`. You cannot use alias in where condition, you need to use the same expression or use subquery instead.

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c624c/3/0)**

```
SELECT *, (3959 * acos(cos(radians(10.916089)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos( radians(lng) - radians(57.598873)) + sin(radians(10.916089)) * 
sin(radians(lat)))) 
AS distance 
FROM project_details
WHERE (3959 * acos(cos(radians(10.916089)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos( radians(lng) - radians(57.598873)) + sin(radians(10.916089)) * 
sin(radians(lat)))) < 15
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 10;
```

Using subquery:

```
SELECT sub.* 
FROM 
(
  SELECT *, (3959 * acos(cos(radians(10.916089)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos( radians(lng) - radians(57.598873)) + sin(radians(10.916089)) * 
sin(radians(lat)))) 
  AS distance 
  FROM project_details 
) AS sub
WHERE sub.distance < 15 
ORDER BY sub.distance 
LIMIT 0 , 10
```